# AWS : How to filter RDS Global Cluster name using QUERY

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I want to query for AWS RDS Global Cluster without using `--global-cluster-identifier` option because in my automation, my code does not know the identifier so I want to fetch the cluster name using `Engine` and filter on the `GlobalClusterIdentifer` whether it contains the given value or not.

Here is my cli command which displays either **Engine** or **GlobalClusterIdentifer**. How to use --query option and get it done.

`aws rds describe-global-clusters --query 'GlobalClusters[].Engine' --output text`

`aws rds describe-global-clusters --query 'GlobalClusters[].GlobalClusterIdentifer' --output text`

So what I need is, I want to query engine type which is aurora-postgresql and fetch the GlobalClusterIdentfier of the filtered engine.

Could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following

```
aws rds describe-global-clusters --query 'GlobalClusters[?Engine==`aurora-postgresql`].GlobalClusterIdentifier
```

Comment: what if I need to find specific context on the ```GlobalClusterIdentifer```? like say for example, I want to filter only ```DEV```, how do we do that?

Comment: Unsure what do you mean by context? If you mean that the `GlobalClusterIdentifier` has to have the string `DEV` in it, you can try something like `aws rds describe-global-clusters --query 'GlobalClusters[?Engine==\`aurora-postgresql\`] | [?contains(GlobalClusterIdentifier, \`DEV\`)].GlobalClusterIdentifier'` and that will you give you clusters of engine=aurora-postgresql and have the string `DEV` in their identier.